# Calculate the Mean of lists of the same length

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the function

```
genList[n0_]:=Module[{n=n0,list3},list3={0};Do[AppendTo[list3,(RandomChoice[Range[0,100],1][[1]])];If[MemberQ[Drop[list3,-1],Last@list3],Break[]],{i,1,n}];Return[list3]]
```

Which generates the list of integers 0 to 100 until the list becomes non-unique or until the target $n0$ is hit.

From this I generate list of lists.

```
listoflists = Table[genList[100],{i,1,100}]
```

Now if two list are the same length I want to calculate the mean of their components.
That is I have to use `Mean@Flatten@...`. If there is a list of unique length I just need the mean of that list.

I've tried using function like `GroupBy[#,Length]` but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `listoflists`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
listoflists = Table[genList[100], {i, 1, 100}];
mlists = GroupBy[listoflists, Length -> Mean] // KeySort
```

> <|2 -> {0}, 3 -> {29}, 4 -> {151/4},   5 -> {199/5, 142/5, 149/5,
> 318/5, 158/5, 38, 167/5},   6 -> {127/3, 131/3, 161/3, 95/3},   7 ->
> {150/7, 243/7, 333/7, 423/7, 293/7, 202/7, 419/7, 334/7},   8 ->
> {131/4, 363/8, 95/2},   9 -> {541/9, 473/9, 286/9, 623/9, 391/9,
> 305/9, 137/3, 484/9, 464/9},   10 -> {489/10, 26, 47, 493/10, 186/5,
> 449/10, 549/10, 242/5, 583/10,
> 43, 261/5},   11 -> {459/11, 574/11, 496/11, 324/11, 538/11, 269/11},   12 -> {93/2, 239/6, 457/12, 649/12, 475/12, 33, 43},   13
> -> {484/13, 538/13, 543/13, 849/13},   14 -> {657/14, 575/14, 689/14},   15 -> {796/15, 724/15, 39, 598/15, 763/15, 556/15, 628/15},   16 ->
> {639/16},   17 -> {790/17, 944/17, 937/17, 668/17, 838/17, 1138/17,
> 747/17},   18 -> {941/18, 527/9, 911/18}, 19 -> {905/19, 974/19},   20
> -> {471/10},   21 -> {365/7, 381/7, 1063/21, 1273/21, 312/7, 1051/21, 857/21, 375/    7}, 22 -> {1009/22, 541/11, 566/11}, 23 -> {1364/23},
> 26 -> {1277/26}, 29 -> {1267/29}|>

---

Also try:

```
mNlists = GroupBy[listoflists, Length -> N@*Mean] // KeySort
```

---

**UPDATE**

To further reduce the lists generated, use an additional argument:

```
mlists2 = GroupBy[listoflists, Length -> Mean, Mean] // KeySort
```

> <|2 -> 0, 3 -> 29, 4 -> 151/4, 5 -> 189/5, 6 -> 257/6, 7 -> 2397/56,
> 8 -> 335/8, 9 -> 442/9, 10 -> 5101/110, 11 -> 1330/33, 12 -> 3529/84,
> 13 -> 1207/26, 14 -> 1921/42, 15 -> 310/7, 16 -> 639/16,   17 ->
> 866/17, 18 -> 1453/27, 19 -> 1879/38, 20 -> 471/10,   21 -> 8543/168,
> 22 -> 293/6, 23 -> 1364/23, 26 -> 1277/26,   29 -> 1267/29|>

Comment: I've wanted to have the Mean of the Flattened lists. 
You generate List of Means. 
For future readers this can be achieved by 'Map[Mean, mlists]'.
(Mean of multiple "Means" is the same as Mean of the whole set if they have the same weight. Which they have thanks to the same length.)

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Please see update.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways is as follows.

```
Table[Mean@Flatten[GatherBy[listoflists, Length][[j]]], 
{j, 1,  Dimensions[GatherBy[listoflists, Length]][[1]]}]
```

> `{779/16, 4582/105, 27, 392/9, 0, 521/15, 332/9, 4747/99, 3404/81, 2251/48, 2461/50, 1134/25, 1039/21, 1319/27, 2973/56, 4164/95,  1422/35, 3131/80, 39/2, 2421/52, 3527/72, 525/11, 2398/51, 1373/27,  1473/31, 1112/23}`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility with `Merge`:

```
list = Table[genList[100], {i, 1, 100}];

res = Merge[Mean @* N] @ MapApply[{Length[{##}] -> {##}} &] @ list;
```

A simple query:

```
res[3]
```

{0., 67., 27.5}

Use `Flatten` to move up one level:

```
res = Merge[Mean @* Flatten @* N] @ MapApply[{Length[{##}] -> {##}} &] @ list;

res[3]
```

31.5

Transform `Association` to `List`:

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ res
```

{{2, 0.}, {3, 31.5}, {4, 5.5}, {5, 33.}, {6, 36.1667}, {7,
42.2286}, {8, 40.875}, {9, 48.7619}, {10, 49.0667}, {11,
39.6364}, {12, 53.0139}, {13, 46.7019}, {14, 42.7946}, {15,
45.4333}, {16, 54.75}, {17, 46.7206}, {18, 52.9167}, {19, 46.}, {20,
51.6833}, {21, 52.5119}, {22, 48.8636}, {23, 53.}, {24,
50.3611}, {26, 51.4038}}

Answer (score 1):

Although not an answer to your question, I should point out that your `genList` function could be coded more efficiently; for example,

```
genList2[n0_] := NestWhileList[RandomInteger[100] &, 0, UnsameQ, All, n0]
```

This function runs about 2.5 times as fast as yours.  I'm sure that others who are more skilled than I, could improve upon this even further.

Note that in either case, `genList` will always generate a $0$ as the first element of the list, and the last element will be a duplicate of another element except when the list reaches a length of $n_0 + 1$.  You could easily modify this if needed.

As for the means by length groups, `GroupBy` is the natural choice, as shown in the already accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wrote the function in the way I did since I will later accumulate to each new element. Is it possible to apply Accumulate to your function?

Comment: @Nitaaa the output of my version of your function is equivalent to yours.  They both return lists.  Why don't you try it?